# Writing to console to an html that is not linked

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

My question is the following: Is it possible to write something from a .js file to the console of a non-linked HTML file?

So I have the following setup: When clicking on a button on html_1(index.html) it opens a new window and this window has an HTML called html_2(numero.html). I would like when the popup window opens to write something (with onload) in the console of index.html. Both HTML files are linked to their own separate .js files (index.js and numero.js). I wanna write to the console from numero.js to index.html tho they are not linked.

Is this even possible?

what I have at the moment.

**HTML Index**
`<button onclick="newWindow();" id="ventana" >ACIERTA NUMERO</button>` opens the new window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="objectosPredef.js"></script>
    <title>Actividad 2</title>
</head>
<body onload="listaPropiedades()">
    <div id="listaPropiedades"></div>
    
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="entra tu nombre" />
    <button onclick="crearCookie();">Click</button>
    <button onclick="newWindow();" id="ventana" >ACIERTA NUMERO</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Index.js**

```
function newWindow(url, title, w, h) {
    var url = "numero.html";
    var title = "";
    var w = 300;
    var h = 300;
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

**HTML numero**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="numero.js"></script>
    <title>count down</title>
</head>
<body onload="windowTimer()">
    <div id="random"></div>
    <div id="timer"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Numero JS**

```
function windowTimer() {
    consoleLog();

    var sec = 8;
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec + " :segundos";
        
        sec--;
        if (sec == -1) {
            window.close();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function consoleLog() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = "Numero aleatorio: " + x;
}
```

At the moment it just writes the random number to the windows but it should go to the console log of index.html.
I could not find anything regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use something like a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to communicate between parent and popup - and use that to trigger the writing to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the comment I made I quickly rattled up a small demo with 2 files, `index.html` and `numero.html`, as per the question.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Index.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button onclick="newWindow();" id="ventana">ACIERTA NUMERO</button>
        
        
        <script>
            function newWindow( url = "numero.html", title = "", w = 300, h = 300 ) {
                var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
                var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
                return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            }
        
        
            let oChannel=new BroadcastChannel( 'numero' );
                oChannel.addEventListener('message',(e)=>{
                    if( e.data.number )console.info('Random Number generated in "numero.html": %s', e.data.number )
                    else console.info( e.data.data )
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**numero.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Numero.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="random"></div>
        <div id="timer"></div>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
            
                let oChannel=new BroadcastChannel( 'numero' );
                
                const Log=()=>{
                    let i=Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 11 ) );
                    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = "Numero aleatorio: " + i;
                    console.info('Numero aleatorio: %d',i);
                    return i;
                };
                
                function windowTimer() {
                    let sec=8;
                    
                    setInterval(function () {
                        if( sec > 0 ){
                            oChannel.postMessage({data:sec})
                            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec + " :segundos";
                        }else if( sec==0 ) {
                            oChannel.postMessage({data:'Goodbye'});
                            window.close();
                        }
                        
                        sec--;
                        
                    }, 1000 );
                };
                
                let _random_number=Log();
                oChannel.postMessage( { data:'loaded', number:_random_number } );
                
                windowTimer();
            })
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both pages must create their own connection to a common channel - the name is arbitrary but must be the same in both. The `index` page `listens` for messages from the child popup page `numero.html` and displays the data that is sent by the popup using the `postMessage` function.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and i kind of understand what you are doing but i'm not getting it to work ... So this is for beginner Javascript students and in my book I could not find anything regarding your method. The question i'm presented with is this: "Program in “number.js” that once the HTML is loaded, a random number between 0 and 10 (both included) is generated and displayed by the index.html console."

Comment: that question suggests nothing of two HTML files - simply 1 html page and 1 javascript file which is greatly different to the question posed here. If the `numero.js` file is in `numero.html` but you want to write to the console of `index.html` then you need some method of communication between these elements otherwise they are completely independent.

Comment: Yes that is the end goal. Had a hard time formulation the question

Comment: The 2 pages above that I created will perform that inter-window communication but the only thing not in that equation is the external `numero.js` file - the javascript seen in my `numero.html` file could easily be placed inside `numero.js` in your scenario

Comment: Hi @Professor Abronsius , I've had more time to read about it and i get it ! It just waits for one .js file to "do" something and listen and do an action on the other one. You've been a massive help !

Comment: I am glad that I have been able to offer guidance and help! Good luck with the rest of your coding adventures.